# RoR: Filter generated JSON to certain parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm generating JSON as follows:

```
def suggest_gems
  @allgems = RubyGem.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
  respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @allgems.to_json }
  end
end
```

However, the RubyGem table is quite large, with values for descriptions, links and created, updated at. How can I only output the name and id in the generated JSON to decrease loading times?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured how to do that without changing the `as_json` method or using the `respond_with` statement, by adding a few lines of code. Here's what I did:

```
def suggest_gems (result = [])
   @allgems = RubyGem.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
   @allgems.each { |g|
     result << { :id => g.id, :name => g.name }
     } 
   respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render :json => result.to_json }
   end
end
```

I basically defined an array and associated the `name` and `id` attributes accordingly, then formatted the array as JSON. Shaved around 6 seconds off the loading time :)

Adding this answer here so that others might find it helpful!

Comment: Jesus man, no! I edited my answer with a neater way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You can really clean up your controller method there and achieve what you want like this:

```
def suggest_gems
  @allgems = RubyGem.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
  respond_with(@allgems, :only => [:id, :name])
end
```

Provided you have this at the top of your controller:

```
respond_to :json
```

EDIT

If you don't want to use `respond_to` then do this:

```
def suggest_gems
  @allgems = RubyGem.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
  render :json => @allgems.as_json(:only => [:id, :name])
end
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I don't want to put `respond_to :json` at the top? Is there a way to do this within the method?

Comment: If you want to use `respond_with` you have to have defined your formats in `respond_to` at the top of your controller, otherwise you can use the respond_to block you used in the example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `as_json` in your model to return only the attributed you want to send back.

```
def as_json(options)
  super(only: [:id, :name])
end
```

Comment: argh, isn't there a less obtrusive way to do this? I'm not keen on doing that since I'm using other methods to get JSON which require those fields...

Comment: then use the `options` parameter and send a certain flag and check on for it inside the `as_json`